# AppStore: changing the icon after the app is published?

Tags: iphone, app-store

My app is already available on the appstore, but after getting some feedback I'm having second thoughts about the icon.

I know the large version of the icon is supposed to look like the device version. But what if I upload a different one, without changing the binary icon, now that the app is already published? Could that get my app removed?

And if I decide to also change the binary icon and re-upload a binary with just that change, would that be considered as an update and go through the review process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They shouldn't care if you update the store images/text, as long as it still looks reasonable. If you post an update, it will go through "review", but if the update change notes say that you only updated the icon, they'll likely pass it through pretty quickly.

You could always send an email to the App Store help email (it's listed on a bunch of the iTunes Connect pages), and see what they say. They've gotten back to me relatively quickly every time I've asked them a question.

I don't think your icon looks all that bad, actually.

Comment: thanks mark :) good to know. I have the feeling it goes a bit unnoticed on the appstore, on those bright backgrounds.
could you give me that help mail? I've been looking for that like crazy, where did you find it? The "contact us" section only shows an irritating mix of FAQs and forms..

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible, when your app uploaded and successfully published then after we cant change the app icon ....so you have to upload again with different icon. 
Thanks

Comment: Is this true? Chosen answer states otherwise